# C++ receiving ListBox messages

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox, handle, message

I want to handle the user's doubleclick over a ListBox, but there's no way to handle the listbox activity because it doesn't send a message to the window. I have this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
             switch(LOWORD(wParam))
             {
                  case IDC_LISTBOX1:
                  {
                       if(HIWORD(wParam) == LBN_DBLCLK)
                       {
                            //...
                       }
                       //...
                  }
             //...
             }
        //...
        }
    //...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I handle the listbox messages?

Comment: From MSDN: "This notification code is sent only by a list box that has the LBS_NOTIFY style."